# .bat set /p menu - If the variable isn't already defined, output it to a separate .cmd

Tags: variables, batch-file, menu

I have a .bat that is a simple menu, that calls other commands based on the input. Is it possible to set it up where if the input isn't a variable that's already defined, to start a command prompt, pass the variable to the command prompt, and go back to the main menu of the original .bat?

Example: If I type 1 or 2, it does what 1 or 2 is supposed to do and returns to the top of the main menu. If I type any other command, like "ping 127.0.0.1" it makes the command and argument a variable, opens a new .cmd, passes the command and argument to the command prompt, and the original script returns to the top of the main menu.

```
:start
echo 1) option 1
echo 2) option 2
set /p a=insert option: 
IF %errorlevel%==1 goto start
IF %a%==1 goto command1
if %a%==2 goto command2
if %a%== Any other variable start .cmd with custom variable && goto start

:command1
blah blah
goto start
:command2
blah blah
goto start
```

Comment: You don't need an `if` for the 'else' statement, as it has dropped through all the other options. So how about `start %a% && goto start` given that `start echo hello!` opens a command window with the echo. Or did you want it to appear with the command line filled in but waiting for enter to be pressed? That's a bit more tricky.

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement the else statement. I've tried multiple different ways, and it just closes the script.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want if I understand your question correctly.

```
:start
echo 1) option 1
echo 2) option 2
set /p "a=insert option:" 
IF NOT DEFINED a goto start
IF "%a%"=="1" goto command1
IF "%a%"=="2" goto command2

cmd /c %a%
goto start

:command1
blah blah
goto start
:command2
blah blah
goto start
```

Comment: Holy crap. Can't believe I was making it so difficult. I was trying so many other possibilities, and the answer was the simple one. Thank you!

Comment: I take that back - It doesn't work completely. It DOES allow me to pick my options and do what it is supposed to do, however, it only allows one-word commands. For example, if I type "powershell" to launch powershell, it works. If I type any other command that has an argument, it doesn't work, such as ping 127.0.0.1, or qwinsta /server:[server].

Comment: It should work now.  Need quotations around strings containing spaces when doing if expressions.